# Simple std::string replace in C++

Tags: c++, date, replace

I am using the following code for replacing special characters in a `system date` format in Windows OS.

But I can only replace one character.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string str("10/16/13");
    string str2("/");
    str.replace(str.find(str2),str2.length(),"-");
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10-16/13
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I don't know C++ well enough to remember if there is a `replaceAll` function, but you can try looping until `str.find(str2)` returns failure (meaning there are no more special characters to replace).

Comment: Of course you only replace one character, did you bother to read the documentation for `std::string::replace(size_type, size_type, const char*)` to see what it does?!  You told the program to replace one character starting at the location of the first `'/'` ... of course that's what it does!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: [off-topic] Is there a typo in the current draft? It says both "index_sequence" and "integer_sequence"...

Comment: @KerrekSB, both are correct, they're different things, see the `<utility>` synopsis, see also https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/183

Comment: @JonathanWakely: oh, alright, thanks. I'll have to reread that section...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only want to replace single characters then you can use [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) from the `<algorithm>` header:

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '/', '-');
```

This will replace all `'/'` in your string by `'-'`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you must replace manually

```
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if (str[i] == '/')
        str[i] = '-';
}
```